# What is the name of the scientific study of hypothesis formation?

Tags: learning

As a layperson, I am interested about the scientific method but whenever I search it online I get endless results about how to formulate and test hypotheses for the purpose of writing a scientific paper.

I'm trying to find the term of the process by which people make and test informal theories and hypotheses during their daily lives.

Example
A young child touches an unfamiliar object and, purely by coincidence, there is a distant clap of thunder.  The child 'hypothesized' that the touch caused the clap of thunder. This is now testable because the child can repeat the experiment.

If I want to read more about this in psychology, what do I put in my search engine to avoid getting thousands of results about null hypotheses and t-tests?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One umbrella term is **causal reasoning**, though this is a bit broader since there are theories of causal reasoning that are not about hypothesis testing.

A Google Scholar search for ["causal reasoning psychology"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=causal+reasoning+psychology&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C15) generates several hundred thousand hits, and the first page is full of relevant papers.

Getting more specific, [Klayman & Ha (1987)](http://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/0033-295X.94.2.211) wrote an influential article about the kinds of hypothesis testing you describe. Looking at [the papers that cite that article](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=1954141597807453515&as_sdt=800005&sciodt=0,15&hl=en) might give you some additional leads into the literature.

Comment: Thanks. I'll spend some time exploring your leads. It's clear that in many cases I need access to online publications in order to read more than the abstracts but I may be able to arrange that. I'll be dropping in from time to time to see if there are other developments. Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually called *abductive* reasoning. As for how it the hypotheses are generated, one way is through analogical matching and inference (search google scholar for Analogico-deductive reasoning, for example).